# Azure Function Load Test VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-devops, performance-testing, azure-functions

I have azure function which is service bus topic trigger that stores data in a database.

However, is there a way I can load test the same and get the statistics out?

I have used visual studio web performance tests and load tests to perform load tests on web api's but not quite sure, how can something similar be done for functions.

Anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 1):

I usually write a small console application which sends data to Service Bus.

This is a bit more manual than firing VSTS tests, but you then get the full control over the payload, serialization, quantity and pace of messages. And it really takes like 30 minutes to make a simple one.

Answer (score 0):

You might use [loader.io](https://loader.io/) to run the tests. They have a free plan to run 10k requests monthly.